# SharePoint Designer prompts for credentials when edited from IE8

Tags: sharepoint

Our intranet is hosted using the free SharePoint services on Windows 2003. Consider the following page:

http://vserver003/help/technology/multimedia/multimedia.htm

On selecting "Edit with Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer" from IE8, SPD launches, opens the website and then the selected page - all is well.

In order to make moving the intranet easier, we've set-up a DNS setting called intranet.company.local so you can also access the intranet that way:

http://intranet.company.local/help/technology/multimedia/multimedia.htm

However, when you edit this page, SPD designer prompts you for credential, i.e. domain\username and password. If you enter the details it opens fine. If you don't enter the details, the page still opens but not the website.

Any ideas have to get around this prompt? Haven't a clue where to start looking.

Thanks, Rob.

PS. The same prompt occurs if you use the physical IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE uses integrated authenication to provide seamless signon. To prevent you from sending the data out of the network, it will by default only send the integrated authenication handshake within the local network.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063

will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this - pointed me in the right direction. Manually adding intranet.company.local as an intranet site in IE8 settings allowed the page to load without a prompt. Cheers, Rob.